# N Queens in Python using backtracking

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, backtracking, n-queens

I write this solution to the popular [N Queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) problem using backtracking algorithm. I am relatively new to Python. I would like to know what are the ways to refactor this code and also code style of Python in general.

```
def isSafe (board, row, col):
    # check left row
    for y in range(col):
        if board[row][y] == 1:
            return False
    # check diagonal left top
    for x, y in zip(range(row, -1, -1), range(col, -1, -1)):
        if board[x][y] == 1:
            return False
    # check diagonal left bottom
    for x, y in zip(range(row, N, 1), range(col, -1, -1)):
        if board[x][y] == 1:
            return False

    return True

def generateSolution(board, col):
    # terminating condition
    # all columns covered
    global N
    if col >= N:
        return True
    # loop over all the rows
    for i in range(N):
        if isSafe(board, i, col) == True:
            board[i][col] = 1
            # recursively place other queens
            if generateSolution(board, col + 1) == True:
                return True
            # unmark queen spot
            board[i][col] = 0
    # backtrack
    return False


N = int(input())
startCol = 0
board = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
# print(board)

if generateSolution(board, startCol) == False:
    print("No Solution Exists")
else:
    print("Solution exists")
    print(board)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## PEP 8

There is a generally accepted style for Python known as [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Most notably `camelCase` functions/methods should become `snake_case`. There are some other issues with stylistic conventions, I would give the document I linked to an overview.

## Main Function

I would advise you add [a main function to your program.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648) The main reason being: If I want to use the functions from your script, when I import your script I probably don't want to actually run your program, just use `generateSolution` and `isSafe`. So:

```
N = int(input())
startCol = 0
board = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
# print(board)

if generateSolution(board, startCol) == False:
    print("No Solution Exists")
else:
    print("Solution exists")
    print(board)
```

Becomes:

```
def main():
    N = int(input())
    startCol = 0
    board = [[0 for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]

    if generateSolution(board, startCol) == False:
        print("No Solution Exists")
    else:
        print("Solution exists")
        print(board)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Avoid global

You should almost always not use the `global` keyword. In this case: just pass `N` into your `generateSolution` function, i.e. `generate_solution(board, col, N)`.

## Naming

I am not entirely sure how your code works (I am, ashamedly, unfamiliar with the N-Queen problem). I assume `N` refers to the number of queens? I would recommend that you call it `queen_count` or something of the sort. In addition, `generate_solution` is rather unspecific. I would call it (possibly) `n_queen_solvable`.

## Does `generate_solution` actually do that?

I mentioned changing it to the name `n_queen_solvable` because you have return a truth value. I would expect a function like that to actually give me a configuration, not answer whether a solution exists or not. You may want to refactor this into two functions: `n_queen_solvable` and `gen_queen_config` or something of the sort.

## Default parameters

You seem to want to start at the zeroith column. Makes sense. Instead of explicitly passing the `startCol` explicitly, I would just make `col` [default to 0](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). This is done by changing:

```
def generateSolution(board, col):
```

to

```
def generateSolution(board, col=0):
```

Comment: There’s also the `generate` special meaning given Python’s generator objects, yet the method is not yielding anything.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @Dair's suggestions. Also, your `isSafe` (which should be called `is_safe` - snake_case is standard in Python) can be simplified, although I'm a little shaky on what you're trying to accomplish with your logic.

First, I'll suggest that you rename your arguments to `row_index` and `col_index`.

I had started re-writing your `for` loops as list comprehensions using `any` (which you should still do), but I ran into some questionable logic.

You say "check left row", by which I think you actually mean "check the left-hand side of the row containing (row_index, col_index)". If that's true, why are you iterating with `y`? Isn't that `x`?

Answer (score 1):

@Dair's answer is good, but there was something else that hasn't been mentioned:

## Don't compare to Boolean values

- Instead of `if foo == True`, write `if foo`
- Instead of `if foo == False`, write `if not foo`

Comparing to Boolean values is always unnecessary because the values will already be coerced into Boolean values in the appropriate contexts. While the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) does say "Explicit is better than implicit", Boolean comparison looks like nonstandard Python code, and is a bit of a code smell for me.